# Semigroup generation

Tags: semigroup-of-operators

For an operator $(A,\mathcal{D}(A))$ on a Banach space $X$ define on $\mathcal{X} := X \times X$ the
operator matrix
$$\mathcal{A}=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    A & 0 \\
    0 & A \\
  \end{array}
\right)$$

with domain $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A}) := \mathcal{D}(A) \times D(A).$

I want to show that the following assertions are equivalent.

(i) $A$ generates a strongly continuous semigroup on $X$.

(ii) $\mathcal{A}$ generates a strongly continuous semigroup on  $\mathcal{X}$.